# Haskell strange (to me) behavior

Tags: haskell, computation

I am working on 99 problems of Haskell (https://wiki.haskell.org/99_questions/1_to_10)
, I have a question regarding to problem # 8.

```
8 Problem 8
(**) Eliminate consecutive duplicates of list elements.

If a list contains repeated elements they should be replaced with a single copy of the element. The order of the elements should not be changed.
```

I've solved this problem with foldr function successfully.

```
compress :: Eq e => [e] -> [e]
compress =  let f v [] = [v]
                f v acc 
                        | head acc == v = acc
                        | otherwise = v:acc
            in foldr f []
```

But when I try to solve the same problem with recursion like this:

```
compress' :: Eq e => [e] -> [e]
compress' = let f acc [] = acc
                f [] (x:xs) = f [x] xs
                f acc (x:xs) | x == last acc = acc ++ f acc xs
                             | otherwise = f (acc ++ [x]) xs 
            in f []
```

I see really strange behavior. I see this result of this function:

```
compress' "aaaabccaadeeee"
"aaaabcabcaabcadeabcadeabcadeabcade"
```

But if I add break point at line

```
compress' = let f acc [] = acc
```

it gives me correct result:

```
ghci> compress' "aaaabccaadeeee"
"aaaabcabcaabcadeabcadeabcadeabcade"
ghci> :break 304
Breakpoint 7 activated at haskell-tut.hs:304:28-30
ghci> compress' "aaaabccaadeeee"
"aaaabcabcaabcadeabcadeabcadeStopped in Main.compress'.f, haskell-tut.hs:304:28-30
_result :: [Char] = _
acc :: [Char] = "abcade"
[haskell-tut.hs:304:28-30] ghci> :con
abcade"
ghci>
```

I feel like it is some thing about Haskell laziness.... It is my best assumption. 
Can any one explain why do I get this odd result during execution and correct result during execution with breakpoint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem comes from the expression below:

```
x == last acc = acc ++ f acc xs
```

It doesn't need to append the `acc` string at the beginning of the result, so the correction should be:

```
x == last acc = f acc xs
```

Note that `acc` contains the correct result you want, i.e. the string without consecutive duplicates, hence you can see the correct result `acc :: [Char] = "abcade"` at the break point when the input list is `[]`. But when it returns, it combines the previous result as `acc ++ "abcade"`, from which the "abcade" at the end of `"aaaabcabcaabcadeabcadeabcadeabcade"`

Comment: You are right, thank you. But why did it show correct output during the debug process after ":continue" command?

Comment: @Pavel  I am not sure how `:continue` to work, but it seems print out the `_result` variable which is bounded to specific break point and not the final result of the function. If you try to set break point to the line `in f []` instead, and try `:countinue` command, it will print `aaaabcabcaabcadeabcadeabcadeabcade"` instead of `abcade"`